# Running Chrome extension periodically using a cronjob

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, cron

I have built a chrome extension that performs a set of actions on a random webpage. The extension seems to work fine and I plan to run it on a VPS running Ubuntu with a XFCE desktop environment. Now the extension needs to perform this tasks on several pages but not concurrently but rather one after the other.

To put it simply, I need to perform the following set of tasks..
**1. Cronjob runs (say every minute) and checks if a task is being executed in chrome.**
A. No

- Pull out a website from a mysql stack
- Start performing the task
- Extension handles saving the output to the database and updates the flag indicating no tasks are running

B. Yes

- Do nothing

I have reached to a point where the extension runs manually, but I need to automate this process and have multiple VPS execute similar tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at several methods to carry out my task using crons, I settled for a better alternative which is offered by the chrome extension itself called [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms).

All I did was create a alarm and made it run every minute

```
chrome.alarms.create('checkNewTasks', {
    when: 1000,
    periodInMinutes: 1
});
```

Works like a charm!